# Multiple cursors in stored procedure for second level lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am passing in two parameters to my stored procedure, `aCode` and `bCode`. I currently only have one cursor `db_cursor`  which is doing a lookup using `aCode`.

However, I need to do a second level match and also have a cursor with `bCode` if no rows returned from first cursor.

Is this possible and how can I achieve this? Basically, I need to obtain the `@ID` before I can do the update/insert operation. @aCode is 90% of time gives me the @ID, however, I need to grab @ID with `@bCode` if `@aCode` doesn't give it. `aCode` and `bCode` are different columns in the database.

Another point to consider is there can be multiple `IDs` mapped to one `aCode` or `bCode` in the database in which case I need to update both Ids.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
    @aCode VARCHAR(50),
    @bCode VARCHAR(50),
    @ClosingPrice DECIMAL(28,4),
    @specialDate DATETIME,
    @person VARCHAR(50),
    @priced INT = NULL
AS
    SET @specialDate = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @specialDate, 112), 8)
    SET @priced = (SELECT CASE WHEN @ClosingPrice > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @ID INT

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT sec.ID
        FROM dbo.Securities sec
        WHERE sec.aCode = @aCode

    OPEN db_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Prices WITH (nolock)
                  WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, @specialDate, specialDate) = 0
                    AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, @specialDate, specialDate) = 0
                    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, @specialDate, specialDate) = 0
                    AND ID = @ID)
        BEGIN
            -- Update
            UPDATE dbo.Prices
            SET ClosingPrice = @ClosingPrice,
                UpdatedDate = GETDATE(),
                DownloadFileID = null,
                UpdatedByUser = @person,
                Priced = @priced
            WHERE
                DATEDIFF(YEAR, @specialDate, specialDate) = 0
                AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, @specialDate, specialDate) = 0
                AND DATEDIFF(DAY, @specialDate, specialDate) = 0
                AND ID = @ID
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- Insert
            INSERT INTO dbo.Prices (ID, ClosingPrice, specialDate, UpdatedDate, UpdatedByUser, Priced)
            VALUES (@ID, @ClosingPrice, @specialDate, GETDATE(), @person, @priced)
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ID;
    END

    CLOSE db_cursor
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
END
```

Comment: You mean that you need a completly new cursor with another query? Or in the case there are no rows returned by the first query (with @aCode) populate the cursor with the same query but filtered with @bCode?

Comment: I updated question. Need to obtain @ID before insert/update so if aCode does not give me ID, try with bCode

Comment: What you really need here is a set based approach. Using cursors like this is horrible for performance. And you might want to read up about NOLOCK, it is not a magic go faster button. There are some very serious side affects of that hint. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: The code you posted is quite terrible. I think you can do the entire thing using a single merge statement. You should be aware, though, that in a multi user environment you might have a race condition problem. Read [Dan Guzman's blog post about it.](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2009/01/31/UPSERT-Race-Condition-With-MERGE.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the query that populates the cursor returns any rows if you use `@aCode`. If so, keep the original value, if not `set @aCode = @bCode`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
@aCode VARCHAR(50),
@bCode VARCHAR(50),
@ClosingPrice DECIMAL(28,4),
@specialDate DATETIME,
@person VARCHAR(50),
@priced INT = NULL
AS
    SET @specialDate = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @specialDate, 112), 8)
    SET @priced = (SELECT CASE WHEN @ClosingPrice > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @ID INT
   IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT sec.ID
        FROM dbo.Securities sec
        WHERE sec.aCode = @aCode) SET @aCode = @bCode;

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT sec.ID
        FROM dbo.Securities sec
        WHERE sec.aCode = @aCode

    OPEN db_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ID

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Prices WITH (nolock)
              WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, @specialDate, specialDate) = 0
                AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, @specialDate, specialDate) = 0
                AND DATEDIFF(DAY, @specialDate, specialDate) = 0
                AND ID = @ID)
        BEGIN
        -- Update
            UPDATE dbo.Prices
            SET ClosingPrice = @ClosingPrice,
                UpdatedDate = GETDATE(),
                DownloadFileID = null,
                UpdatedByUser = @person,
                Priced = @priced
            WHERE
                DATEDIFF(YEAR, @specialDate, specialDate) = 0
                AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, @specialDate, specialDate) = 0
                AND DATEDIFF(DAY, @specialDate, specialDate) = 0
                AND ID = @ID
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
        -- Insert
            INSERT INTO dbo.Prices (ID, ClosingPrice, specialDate, UpdatedDate, UpdatedByUser, Priced)
            VALUES (@ID, @ClosingPrice, @specialDate, GETDATE(), @person, @priced)
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ID;
    END

    CLOSE db_cursor
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a lot of detail to work with here but pretty sure this cursor could be removed and use a set based along these lines.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
(
    @aCode VARCHAR(50),
    @bCode VARCHAR(50),
    @ClosingPrice DECIMAL(28,4),
    @specialDate DATETIME,
    @person VARCHAR(50),
    @priced INT = NULL
) as
    set nocount on;

    UPDATE p
    SET ClosingPrice = @ClosingPrice,
        UpdatedDate = GETDATE(),
        DownloadFileID = null,
        UpdatedByUser = @person,
        Priced = @priced
    from Prices p
    join Securities s on s.ID = p.ID
    WHERE convert(date, @specialDate) = convert(date, specialDate)
        and s.aCode in (@aCode, @bCode)


    if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        INSERT INTO dbo.Prices
        (
            ID
            , ClosingPrice
            , specialDate
            , UpdatedDate
            , UpdatedByUser
            , Priced
        )
        select sec.ID
            , @ClosingPrice
            , LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @specialDate, 112), 8)
            , GETDATE()
            , @person
            , CASE WHEN @ClosingPrice > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        from dbo.Securities sec
        WHERE sec.aCode in (@aCode, @bCode)
```

Comment: bCode you are looking for in aCode column in database? They are different codes

Comment: I get `multi-part identifier p.ID could not be bound`. Also if there are multiple ID's in database mapped to `aCode` or `bCode` I'd need to update both. can you update ur answer to reflect these ?

Comment: Oops. That would be sec.ID. I can't really just update my answer because I am coding blind. We have no tables, no sample data and no good explanation of what you are trying to accomplish. I attempted to update/insert both codes as best I could with no details.